# how to subtract all pandas dataframe elements with each other easier way?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

let's say I have a dataframe like this

```
name time
a    10
b    30
c    11
d    13
```

now I want a new dataframe like this

```
    name1 name2 time_diff
    a     a      0
    a     b     -20
    a     c     -1
    a     d     -3
    b     a      20
    b     b      0
    b     c      19
    b     d      17
    .....
    .....
    d     d      0
```

nested for loops, lambda function can be used but as the number of elements go above 200, for loops just take too much time to finish or should I say, I always have to interrupt the process. Does someone know a panda query way or something quicker & easier. shape of my dataframe is 1600x2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution with itertools:

```
import itertools
d=pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.product(df.name,df.name)),columns=['name1','name2'])
dic = dict(zip(df.name,df.time))
d['time_diff']=d.name1.map(dic)-d.name2.map(dic)
print(d)
   name1 name2  time_diff
0      a     a          0
1      a     b        -20
2      a     c         -1
3      a     d         -3
4      b     a         20
5      b     b          0
6      b     c         19
7      b     d         17
8      c     a          1
9      c     b        -19
10     c     c          0
11     c     d         -2
12     d     a          3
13     d     b        -17
14     d     c          2
15     d     d          0
```

Comment: as the number of rows are increasing, it's now throwing memory error.

Answer (score 3):

Use cross join first by [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with helper column, get difference and select only necessary columns:

```
df = df.assign(A=1)
df = pd.merge(df, df, on='A', suffixes=('1','2'))
df['time_diff'] = df['time1'] - df['time2']
df = df[['name1','name2','time_diff']]
print (df)
   name1 name2  time_diff
0      a     a          0
1      a     b        -20
2      a     c         -1
3      a     d         -3
4      b     a         20
5      b     b          0
6      b     c         19
7      b     d         17
8      c     a          1
9      c     b        -19
10     c     c          0
11     c     d         -2
12     d     a          3
13     d     b        -17
14     d     c          2
15     d     d          0
```

Another solution with [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) and [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html) by first and second level:

```
df = df.set_index('name')
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.index, df.index], names=['name1','name2'])

df = (df['time'].reindex(mux, level=0)
        .sub(df.reindex(mux, level=1)['time'])
        .rename('time_diff')
        .reset_index())
```

Answer (score 1):

another way would be, `df.apply`

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'col':['a','b','c','d'],'col1':[10,30,11,13]})
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['col'], df['col']], names = ["name1", "name2"])
res=pd.DataFrame(index = index).reset_index()
res['time_diff']=df.apply(lambda x: x['col1']-df['col1'],axis=1).values.flatten()
```

O/P:

```
   name1 name2  time_diff
0      a     a          0
1      a     b        -20
2      a     c         -1
3      a     d         -3
4      b     a         20
5      b     b          0
6      b     c         19
7      b     d         17
8      c     a          1
9      c     b        -19
10     c     c          0
11     c     d         -2
12     d     a          3
13     d     b        -17
14     d     c          2
15     d     d          0
```